# Change the width of text input in a Kendo UI grid with InCell editing

Tags: input, kendo-grid, edit

Basically, I have a kendo UI gri with InCell editing. This is what it looks like.

[image]

This is what it looks like when I edit a cell.

[image]

And this is what I want it to look like.
I don't even know if that's possible, but it's on my requirements list. Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes You Can , Use the editor property

```
columns: [
        {
            field: "Your Field",
            title: "Your Field Name",
            width: "20%",
            editor: function (container, options) {
                $('<textarea data-bind="value: ' + options.field + '"></textarea>').appendTo(container);
            }
        },
```

as the Text area behaviour you can drag right and bottom to disable dag to bottom use below css

```
textarea {
    min-height: 75px;
    resize: vertical !important;
}
```